# C# Boframework Chain Switch

Tags: c#, botframework

Example of problem: [Image conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPjdF.png)

The image bellow indicates that I had to answer the question twice before the answer displayed. By any chance,anybody knows what can be wrong in the code and how can I fix it?

```
  public IDialog<IntroForm> BuildChain()
    {
        return Chain
            .From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(BuildIntroForm))
            .Switch(
                new Case<IntroForm, IDialog<IntroForm>>((msg) =>
                {
                    return true;  //Debug
                }, (ctx, msg) =>
                {
                    return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(BuildPCForm));
                }),
                new DefaultCase<IntroForm, IDialog<IntroForm>>((ctx, msg) =>
                {
                   //Code ...
                })
            )
            .Unwrap()
            .PostToUser();
    }

    private IForm<IntroForm> BuildPCForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<IntroForm>()
            .Message("Rozsvítí se nějaké LED, ozve se beeb kód, ozve se zvuk větráčku, jakákoli reakce na spouštěcí tlačítko?") //Czech language
            .Build();
    }

    private IForm<IntroForm> BuildIntroForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<IntroForm>()
             .
             . //Code ..
            .Field(new FieldReflector<IntroForm>(nameof(IntroForm.Problem))
             .SetPrompt(
                    new PromptAttribute(
                        "Máte problém s ...? {||}"))) //Form from the image
            .Build();
    }
```

Comment: Just a guess: I see a return Chain and then another return Chain nested in it. Maybe that is the cause?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis Thanks. But how fix it?

Comment: why not remove the inner one at that code? I see a .Switch there and a "return true". Does using "return false" there fix it? Most probably .Switch is not needed at all and you have to just use new DefaultCase in its place. Not familiar with that API, just guessing from the code structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution

Use `FormDialog.FromForm(BuildPCForm,FormOptions.PromptInStart))` add FormOptions.PromptInStart

Complete code

```
public IDialog<IntroForm> BuildChain()
{
    return Chain
        .From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(BuildIntroForm))
        .Switch(
            new Case<IntroForm, IDialog<IntroForm>>((msg) =>
            {
                return true;  //Debug
            }, (ctx, msg) =>
            {
                return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(BuildPCForm,FormOptions.PromptInStart));
            }),
            new DefaultCase<IntroForm, IDialog<IntroForm>>((ctx, msg) =>
            {
               //Code ...
            })
        )
        .Unwrap()
        .PostToUser();
}

private IForm<IntroForm> BuildPCForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<IntroForm>()
        .Message("Rozsvítí se nějaké LED, ozve se beeb kód, ozve se zvuk větráčku, jakákoli reakce na spouštěcí tlačítko?") //Czech language
        .Build();
}

private IForm<IntroForm> BuildIntroForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<IntroForm>()
         .
         . //Code ..
        .Field(new FieldReflector<IntroForm>(nameof(IntroForm.Problem))
         .SetPrompt(
                new PromptAttribute(
                    "Máte problém s ...? {||}"))) //Form from the image
        .Build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has helped :)